# Use a separate variable for each template created

Tags: meteor

Here's what I have:

home.jade

```
body
  div {{> hello 'World' }}
  div {{> hello 'Town' }}
```

hello.jade

```
template(name="hello")
  button.sayHello Say {{name}}
```

hello.coffee

```
obj = {}
Template.hello.created = ->
  obj.name = this.data

Template.hello.helpers
  name: -> obj.name

Template.hello.events
  'click .sayHello': -> console.log obj.name
```

It displays the two buttons correctly ("Say World" and "Say Town"). But if you click any button the output is always "Town" (the last one to be created and rendered).

How can I share a variable in a template so that it's unique for each template created? In other words I want to be able to set values on a variable in the created event and then be able to access them in the events (for each template created/rendered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass an object as the context to the `hello` template. Try replacing all of your code with:

### hello.jade

```jade
body
  div {{> hello name='World' }}
  div {{> hello name='Town' }}

template(name="hello")
  button.sayHello Say {{name}}
```

### hello.coffee

```coffee
Template.hello.events
  'click .sayHello': (e, t) ->
    console.log t.data.name
```

Recommended reading:

- [guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/)
- [spacebars-secrets](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/spacebars-secrets-exploring-meteor-new-templating-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

In your example obj is shared by every instance of template hello.
Try to use instance of template as a key in obj:

```
obj = {}
Template.hello.created = ->
  // this is instance of template
  obj[this] = {name : this.data }


Template.hello.helpers
  // here is problem, there is no access to template instance:
  // see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1529
  // name: -> obj[this].name

Template.hello.events
  'click .sayHello': (e, tmpl)-> console.log obj[tmpl].name
```

Comment: It's a partial solution because it can't be used with the helpers. Another thing is that obj[this] also refers to the last template. In my test I had to replace it with an id of sorts. e.g. obj[this.data.id] = "..."